# How to check which one of the excel sheets has a specific word inside using python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, string

I have been building a project in python and i have been having a little problem when working with python and excel. I have an excel document with 50+ sheets(Sheet1, Sheet2, ...) and I want to find which of the sheets has a word inside them. For example: I am looking for the sheets that have the word "work"(in one of the cells) inside them, and as result have the name of the sheets that have that word inside them(the result can be multiple sheets for this example, like Sheet4, Sheet43, Sheet50). Thank you for reading and for the help.

I tried to find a answer by myself and I failed. Then I tried to find the answer on the internet and most of the posts discus the next problem: finding the sheets that have a specific word in their name. This is not for what I am looking. I am looking for finding the sheets that have a specific word in them(not in the name but in one of the cells). So far I have been using pandas for context.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import pandas as pd
    exel_data = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx")

##### converting into comma-separated values
    exel_data.to_csv("data.txt")
##### Open in read mode   
    file = open("ptry.txt", "r")
##### reading comma-separated values
    file_str = filex.read()
##### Spliting it on the basis on , (in my case) you can use whatever suit your data type and creating a list
    file_list = file_str.split(",")
#### if "hello world is in it return true else false    
    if "hello world" in file_list:
        print("True")
    else:
        print("false")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
xls = load_workbook(filename= excel_path , data_only=True)

for i in xls.sheetnames:
  ws = xls[str(i)]
  for num_row in range (1, ws.max_row +1):
    # print(ws.max_row)
    if ws['A{}'.format(num_row)].value=='work':
        print (str(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sheet_name=None and a list comp:

```
import pandas as pd


file = "path/to/file/file.xlsx"
search_for = "work"

sheet_mapping = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=None).items()
found_in = [sheet for sheet, df in sheet_mapping if search_for in df.values.astype(str)]
print(found_in)
```